# query for a particular userId within json placeholder

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, request

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com provides free sample data.

using something like this:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{id}')
```

I can get the todos with a particular id. However, I want to get todos with a particular userId. How is that possible? Is there any way to include that in the query or should I just load all data and then filter out the ones with my desired userIds?

This is how the data looks like:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

Comment: Maybe https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=2 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?userId=4')
print(r.text)
```